# How to deal with cordova plugin when developing in browser?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an application Ionic, Angular and Cordova and I'm looking for the best way to call Cordova plugins in Javascript while developing in the browser. What is the best practice? And how can I make it DRY?

Let's say I'm using the Cordova globalization plugin. In order to prevent any errors when testing inside a browser, I would have to wrap the code inside a try and catch like this:

```
try {
   navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(onSuccess, onError);
}
catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Or I would test if `navigator.globalization` is defined like this:

```
 if(navigator.globalization) {
     navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(onSuccess, onError);
 }
```

But is there any way I can avoid doing that every time I need to call a Cordova plugin?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Is your question about testing or using cordova plugins? Please add a little more detail as to exactly what you would like to get out of this question.

Comment: Thank you @Blunderfest. I just edited my question. I hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `cordova.js` is only available when you are running application in device or emulator. So there is no way that you can use cordova plugins in browsers.As you need to put a check `if(navigator.globalization)` on every plugin call for testing on browsers, so i will suggest you to make your own wrapper or functions above these calls, some sort of global function which will call these plugins functions.
Here is a sample with plain javascript.

```
function MyGlobalizationService(){
};

MyGlobalizationService.prototype.getPreferredLanguage = function(onSuccess, onError){
 if(navigator.globalization) {
     navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(onSuccess, onError);
 }
}

window.myGlobalizationService = new MyGlobalizationService();
```

And then use `window.myGlobalizationService` functions anywhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I was looking for. And, I forgot to mention I'm using Angular, so I guess I can basically just put that in an Angular Service.

Comment: @PhilippeHuot Good to hear that. Yes just make a service for this in angular.  Mark answer as accepted and do upvote  if it helped you :)