# use cordova plugins inside ionic project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new to Ionic and Cordova . I am trying to add a plugin

1.Created an ionic app using `"ionic start myproj"`

2.Added a cordova plugin using follwoing comment

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.helloworld.git
```

3.Added `navigator.helloworld.say();`inside the ionic app.js as mentioned below

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)


    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }

    navigator.helloworld.say();
  });
})
```

when i am running the code through "ionic serve"..I am not getting the hello alert but i am getting the following error in the console as below

" can not read property 'type' of undefined for the line **navigator.helloworld.say();**

Please let me know do i need to add any entries to any xml for mannual plugin addition or do i miss anything?

Comment: You don't have a navigator since you're testing your app in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

Plugins only work on real device or emulator, because they need `cordova.js` to be functional, which is only available when you run application on device or emulator. See this line your `index.html` :

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

`cordova.js` include all plugins js to your application.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191333/how-to-deal-with-cordova-plugin-when-developing-in-browser/32191891#32191891) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First solution:
 1. check that this plugin is wrapped by http://ngcordova.com/.

Second solution:
2. write wrapper =  angular factory:

```
.factory('factoryname', ['$q', '$window','$state', function ($q, $window, $state) {
return {
callStateListener: function () {
            var q = $q.defer();

            if (!$window.cordova) {
              q.reject('Not supported without cordova.js');
            } else {
              navigator.helloworld.say();
             return q.promise;
          },
```

3th solutions:
add ['$window'] dependency to module you want use plugin. and use navigator.helloworld.say();

4 th solutions copy and paste this js code into you angular code on top of it and use helloworld.say();

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugins do not work while developing in your browser, because each plugin accesses a specific API (such as camera, microphone, accelerometer) which is not available in your browser. Additionally, some plugins don't work in the emulator, such as the Camera plugin, so development on your physical device is required.

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-not-use-cordova-plugins-inside-ionic-project/32459/4