# IBM Cordova push plugin with ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-cloud

Just trying to get the [IBM cordova push plugin](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-core) working with Ionic.  The [documentation](https://www.au-syd.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/gettingstarted/cordova/index.html) is good for Cordova, but there is no guidance for Ionic. Just looking for the best way to approach this.
thanks

Comment: In general there is no difference: because Cordova is behind Ionic FW you can manage Cordova plugins the same way in an Ionic project. In other words the Ionic CLI has all the Cordova CLI commands. So I think this applies also to IMB cordova push plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @beaver mentioned in his comment, there should be no major difference, Cordova is still used in Ionic projects so you can manage cordova plugins in an Ionic project like you'd manage them in a Cordova project. This said, you can follow the same documentation for [setting cordova client plugin for bluemix](https://www.au-syd.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/gettingstarted/cordova/index.html) with the following exceptions:

**In the section titled: Installing the Cordova plug-in**

1. Instead of step 2 of the tutorial, install cordova and ionic using `npm install -g cordova ionic`
2. Instead step 3 of the tutorial, create your ionic project using `ionic start myApp blank`
3. Instead of step 5 and 6 of the tutorial, first add your required platforms using `ionic platform add android` or `ionic platform add ios` then follow step 5 of the tutorial to set the minimum versions.

**In the section titled: Initializing the cordova plug-in**

This is the important part, the IBM bluemix plugin must be initialised after the Ionic framework has completed loading, that's why we need to modify step 1 of this section, instead of adding the initialization code globally in index.js, add it before the end of the `$ionicPlatform.ready` function like the code below

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic']).run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // some initialization code
    // then 
    if(BMSClient)
      BMSClient.initialize("app-route", "app-guide");
  });
})
```

Comment: This works when using a mobile device, but when using 'ionic serve' , I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: BMSClient is not defined" error.

Comment: That's expected in ionic and cordova apps, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191333/how-to-deal-with-cordova-plugin-when-developing-in-browser

The answer of this question can be used to make sure the object is available before using it.